# why does python tell me that my yes variable not defined?

Tags: python, variables, user-input

I wrote this script with Python 2.7:

```
name=raw_input("Hi im a PC, who are you?")

print("Hi " + name + " how are you, are you good?")

answer = raw_input("")

if (answer) == yes:
    print("That's good to hear")
elif (answer) == no:
    print("Oh well")
else:
    print("Sorry, you didnt answer the question properly, Please answer with a yes or no")
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Python27/programs/2", line 4, in 

     if (answer) == yes:

NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

you have no variable named `yes`,
What you are trying to do is compare the user input to the string `"yes"`

which would go like:

```
if answer == "yes":
    # do stuff
```

There is also no need for those brackets around answer.

Answer (score 1):

`answer` is a string and you shall use `answer == "yes"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `"` or `'` in your strings. `yes` is not `"yes"`, and `no` is not `"no"`.

```
#if (answer) == yes:
if (answer) == "yes":

#elif (answer) == no:
elif (answer) == "no":
```

The error `name 'yes' is not defined` is because the interpreter looked for a variable called `yes` because the word is without `"` or `'`. If you write `"yes"` the interpreter will compare the value of `answer` variable with the string `"yes"`.